# react createStackNavigator throws "undefined is not a function" error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm new to React-Native and having a routing issue. My app works fine when I use stackNavigator but as it's deprecated I tried changing to createStackNavigator.

I'm getting the error

> undefined is not a function (evaluating
>   '(0,_reactNavigation.createStackNavigator)')

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7ljX.jpg).

My app.js code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';


import HomeScreen from './app/pages/HomeScreen';
import CreateScreen from './app/pages/CreateScreen';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppStackNavigator/>    
    );
  }
}
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen}, 
  CreateReminders:{
    screen: CreateScreen}
})
```

My dependencies are:

```
{
  "expo": "^30.0.1",
  "expo-cli": "^2.2.0",
  "react": "16.3.1",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz",
  "react-native-modal-filter-picker": "^1.3.4",
  "react-navigation": "^1.6.1"
}
```

I've tried various syntax changes (imports with and without {}, shorthand notation in the constructor) and have reinstalled react and react-navigation.

I'm obviously overlooking something. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're using `react-navigation` v1, so it must be StackNavigator instead of createStackNavigator https://v1.reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html

Comment: That's embarrassing. Thank you for correcting me!